# Building a msi Installer using MSbuild

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration

I have a Dotnet Windows application built using visual studio 2015.

I am trying to automate the build using MSbuild and Jenkins.
The output files are Setup.exe & MyAppSetup.msi.

I want to use MSbuild and the VS2015 solution file, without using the VS IDE.
The Visual studio solution has 6 projects and all the projects should be built together to generate the .msi installer.

The setup.exe and .msi files are being built using the  setup project file(.vdproj).

How do I build the same solution using MSBuild ?

Answer (score 4):

msbuild does not have support for setup projects.

To integrate with Jenkins, you will have to use devenv (VS IDE).

Note: starting VS 2013, vdproj support is provided by an add-in.

Find more information on the following blog: https://juristr.com/blog/2014/03/Jenkins-Build-Setup-Project/